# POST http://localhost:3000/api/devolucions 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm pretty new to javascript, and I'm trying to create a page to return orders for an e-commerce website that I'm creating. I want a customer to be able to start a return when they click the Return Order button on their orders history page. When I click on the Return Order button I'm getting a `POST http://localhost:3000/api/devolucions 400 (Bad Request)`. This post is created in the backend in devolucionRoute.js and called in the frontend in devolucionActions.js.  I'm unsure why I am getting this error, and I would really appreciate any help or guidance on how to fix this issue.
Thank you!

Note: devolucion is the name that I used in place of return

devolucionActions.js

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import {
  DEVOLUCION_CREATE_FAIL,
  DEVOLUCION_CREATE_REQUEST,
  DEVOLUCION_CREATE_SUCCESS,
  DEVOLUCION_DETAILS_FAIL,
  DEVOLUCION_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  DEVOLUCION_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  DEVOLUCION_SUMMARY_REQUEST,
  DEVOLUCION_SUMMARY_SUCCESS,

} from '../constants/devolucionConstants';



export const createDevolucion = (devolucion) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_CREATE_REQUEST, payload: devolucion });
  try {
    const {
      userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    const { data } = await Axios.post('/api/devolucions', devolucion, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    });
    dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_CREATE_SUCCESS, payload: data.devolucion });
    
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: DEVOLUCION_CREATE_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
export const detailsDevolucion = (devolucionId) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: devolucionId });
    const {
      userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/devolucions/${devolucionId}`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
      });
      dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_DETAILS_FAIL, payload: message });
    }
  };


  export const summaryDevolucion = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_SUMMARY_REQUEST });
    const {
      userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.get('/api/devolucions/summary', {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
      });
      dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_SUMMARY_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: DEVOLUCION_CREATE_FAIL,
        payload:
          error.response && error.response.data.message
            ? error.response.data.message
            : error.message,
      });
    }
  };
```

Backend

devolucionRouter.js

```
import express from 'express';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import Order from '../models/orderModel.js';
import Devolucion from '../models/devolucionModel.js';
import User from '../models/userModel.js';
import Product from '../models/productModel.js';
import {isAdmin, isAuth, isSellerOrAdmin} from '../utils.js';


const devolucionRouter = express.Router();


devolucionRouter.get(
  '/mine',
  isAuth,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const devolucion= await Devolucion.find({ user: req.user._id });
    res.send(devolucion);
  })
);
devolucionRouter.post(
  '/',
  isAuth,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.devolucionItems.length === 0) {
      res.status(400).send({ message: 'No Return' });
    } else {
      const devolucion = new Devolucion({
        seller: req.body.orderItems[0].seller,
        orderItems: req.body.orderItems,
        devolucionItems: req.body.devolucionItems,
        shippingAddress: req.body.shippingAddress,
        paymentMethod: req.body.paymentMethod,
        itemsPrice: req.body.itemsPrice,
        itemsProfit: req.body.itemsProfit,
        shippingPrice: req.body.shippingPrice,
        taxPrice: req.body.taxPrice,
        totalPrice: req.body.totalPrice,
        totalProfit: req.body.totalProfit,
        user: req.user._id,
      });
      const createdDevolucion = await devolucion.save();
      res
        .status(201)
        .send({ message: 'New Return Created', devolucion: createdDevolucion });
    }
  })
);

devolucionRouter.get(
  '/:id',
  isAuth,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const devolucion = await Devolucion.findById(req.params.id);
    if (devolucion) {
      res.send(devolucion);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send({ message: 'Return Not Found' });
    }
  })
);


export default devolucionRouter;
```

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import path from 'path';
import userRouter from './routers/userRouter.js';
import productRouter from './routers/productRouter.js';
import orderRouter from './routers/orderRouter.js';
import devolucionRouter from './routers/devolucionRouter.js';
import uploadRouter from './routers/uploadRouter.js';

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/AM', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
});

app.use('/api/uploads', uploadRouter);
app.use('/api/users', userRouter);
app.use('/api/products', productRouter);
app.use('/api/orders', orderRouter);
app.use('/api/devolucions', devolucionRouter);
app.get('/api/config/paypal', (req, res) => {
  res.send(process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID || 'sb');
});
const __dirname = path.resolve();
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads')));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Server is ready');
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Serve at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

OrderHistoryScreen.js (Frontend)

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { listOrderMine, detailsOrder } from '../actions/orderActions';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import {createDevolucion } from '../actions/devolucionActions';
import { DEVOLUCION_CREATE_RESET } from '../constants/devolucionConstants';

export default function OrderHistoryScreen(props) {
  const orderId = props.match.params.id;
  const order = useSelector((state) => state.order);
  const devolucionCreate = useSelector((state) => state.devolucionCreate);
  const {success, devolucion } = devolucionCreate;
  const orderMineList = useSelector((state) => state.orderMineList);
  const { loading, error, orders } = orderMineList;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listOrderMine());
    dispatch(detailsOrder(orderId));
  }, [dispatch, orderId]);
  const placeDevolucionHandler = () => {
    dispatch(createDevolucion({ ...order, devolucionItems: order.orderItems }));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (success) {
      props.history.push(`/devolucion/${devolucion._id}`);
      dispatch({ type: DEVOLUCION_CREATE_RESET });
    }
  }, [dispatch, devolucion, props.history, success]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Order History</h1>
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ACTIONS</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {orders.map((order) => (
              <tr key={order._id}>
                <td>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={placeDevolucionHandler}
                  className="small"
                 // disabled={cart.cartItems.length === 0}
                >
                  Return Order
                </button>
                </td>
             
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

devolucionReducer.js (Frontend)

```
import {
    DEVOLUCION_CREATE_FAIL,
    DEVOLUCION_CREATE_REQUEST,
    DEVOLUCION_CREATE_RESET,
    DEVOLUCION_CREATE_SUCCESS,
    DEVOLUCION_DETAILS_FAIL,
    DEVOLUCION_DETAILS_REQUEST,
    DEVOLUCION_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
    DEVOLUCION_DELETE_REQUEST,
    DEVOLUCION_DELETE_SUCCESS,
    DEVOLUCION_DELETE_FAIL,
    DEVOLUCION_DELETE_RESET,
    DEVOLUCION_SUMMARY_REQUEST,
    DEVOLUCION_SUMMARY_SUCCESS,
    DEVOLUCION_SUMMARY_FAIL,
  } from '../constants/devolucionConstants';
  
  export const devolucionCreateReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case DEVOLUCION_CREATE_REQUEST:
        return { loading: true };
      case DEVOLUCION_CREATE_SUCCESS:
        return { loading: false, success: true, devolucion: action.payload };
      case DEVOLUCION_CREATE_FAIL:
        return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
      case DEVOLUCION_CREATE_RESET:
        return {};
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
  export const devolucionDetailsReducer = (
    state = { loading: true },
    action
  ) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case DEVOLUCION_DETAILS_REQUEST:
        return { loading: true };
      case DEVOLUCION_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
        return { loading: false, devolucion: action.payload };
      case DEVOLUCION_DETAILS_FAIL:
        return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
  
  export const devolucionDeleteReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case DEVOLUCION_DELETE_REQUEST:
        return { loading: true };
      case DEVOLUCION_DELETE_SUCCESS:
        return { loading: false, success: true };
      case DEVOLUCION_DELETE_FAIL:
        return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
      case DEVOLUCION_DELETE_RESET:
        return {};
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

  export const devolucionSummaryReducer = (
    state = { loading: true, summary: {} },
    action
  ) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case DEVOLUCION_SUMMARY_REQUEST:
        return { loading: true };
      case DEVOLUCION_SUMMARY_SUCCESS:
        return { loading: false, summary: action.payload };
      case DEVOLUCION_SUMMARY_FAIL:
        return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```

store.js (frontend)

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { cartReducer } from './reducers/cartReducers';
import {
  devolucionCreateReducer,
  devolucionDeleteReducer,
  devolucionShipReducer,
  devolucionDeliverReducer,
  devolucionDetailsReducer,
  devolucionListReducer,
  devolucionMineListReducer,
  devolucionPayReducer,
  devolucionSummaryReducer,
} from './reducers/devolucionReducers';
import {
  orderCreateReducer,
  orderDeleteReducer,
  orderShipReducer,
  orderDeliverReducer,
  orderDetailsReducer,
  orderListReducer,
  orderMineListReducer,
  orderPayReducer,
  orderSummaryReducer,
  orderReducer,
} from './reducers/orderReducers';
import {
    productCategoryListReducer,
    productCreateReducer,
    productDeleteReducer,
    productDetailsReducer,
    productListReducer,
    productReviewCreateReducer,
    productUpdateReducer,
} from './reducers/productReducers';


const initialState = {
  userSignin: {
    userInfo: localStorage.getItem('userInfo')
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
      : null,
  },  
  cart: {
        cartItems: localStorage.getItem('cartItems')
          ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))
          : [],
        shippingAddress: localStorage.getItem('shippingAddress')
          ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shippingAddress'))
          : {},
          paymentMethod: 'PayPal',
      },
 
};
const reducer = combineReducers({
  devolucionCreate: devolucionCreateReducer,
  devolucionDetails: devolucionDetailsReducer,
  devolucionDelete: devolucionDeleteReducer,
  devolucionSummary: devolucionSummaryReducer,
  productList: productListReducer,
  productDetails: productDetailsReducer, 
  cart: cartReducer,
  order: orderReducer,
  userSignin: userSigninReducer,
  userRegister: userRegisterReducer,
  orderCreate: orderCreateReducer,
  orderDetails: orderDetailsReducer,
  orderPay: orderPayReducer,
  orderMineList: orderMineListReducer,
  orderSummary: orderSummaryReducer,
  userDetails: userDetailsReducer,
  userUpdateProfile: userUpdateProfileReducer,
  userUpdate: userUpdateReducer,
  productCreate: productCreateReducer,
  productUpdate: productUpdateReducer,
  productDelete: productDeleteReducer,
  orderList: orderListReducer,
  orderDelete: orderDeleteReducer,
  orderShip: orderShipReducer,
  orderDeliver: orderDeliverReducer,
  productReviewCreate: productReviewCreateReducer,
  userList: userListReducer,
  userDelete: userDeleteReducer,
  productCategoryList: productCategoryListReducer,
  
});
const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export default store;
```

Comment: I'd start to console log places where you pass your `devolutionItems`, here: `devolucionItems: order.orderItems`,  here `const order = useSelector((state) => state.order);`, here `export const createDevolucion`. There is a lot of code and logic here, it's difficult to figure out the issue

Comment: Where is your reducer function which will process `DEVOLUCION_CREATE_SUCCESS`, etc.? 400 Bad request as per your code is when payload is empty.

Comment: @kiner_shah Hi, I added my devolucionReducer.js, which contains my reducer function that processes DEVOLUCION_CREATE_SUCCESS and my store.js, which contains my reducer functions

Comment: I think this is too difficult to understand it like this, I think you should really debug what's going on.